# VB. NEt Printing Labels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, printing, label

I made a software to print a specific type of labels (100x150) on a TCS Barcode Printer DA200 machine, When I print it prints on two pages disorganized, most of the text is on the first page and the rest on the second. I've tried to change almost every code but it's not working. I would like to make the print responsive and stay on just one page.

The output Code:

```
Sub Print()
    TextBox5.Text = ""
    TextBox5.AppendText("Produced By:" + vbTab + vbTab + "Company")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Address")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "No. 1")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "City")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Product:" + vbTab + vbTab + "SPECIE")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Product Format:" + vbTab + "Fresh Skin OFF Loin")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Grade:" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "GRADE")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Catch Area:" + vbTab + vbTab + "FAO 51")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Storage Instructions:" + vbTab + "0.5º to 1.5º Celcius")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Establishment No.:" + vbTab + "A22.1")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Origin:" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Origin")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Vessel Name/s:" + vbTab + vbTab + vesselcmb.SelectedItem)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Product Date:" + vbTab + vbTab + Date.Now.Date)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Best Before:" + vbTab + vbTab + Date.Now.Date.AddDays(16))
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Project code:" + vbTab + vbTab + voyageprint.Text)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("Net Weight:" + vbTab + vbTab + "")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbTab + "To be further prepared for consumption")
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbNewLine)
    TextBox5.AppendText("" + vbTab + vbTab + "100% Natural")
    '' TextBox5.AppendText(vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + PictureBox1.Text + vbNewLine)
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

The Print Document Code:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim printfont As New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim SizeP As New PaperSize("Label 100x150", 100, 150)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox5.Text, printfont, Brushes.Black, 4, 6)
        '' e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.PictureBox1.Image, 120, 130, PictureBox1.Width - 15, PictureBox1.Height - 25)
    End Sub
```

How it Prints:
[image: How it prints]

Comment: That's crazy bad code. Why put al the text into a `TextBox` when you can put the code to draw each part of the text exactly as and where you want to in the `PrintPage` event handler? get rid of that first method and put all the logic in the `PrintPage` event handler, including as many `DrawString` calls as are required.

Comment: How can I do that? Comment with an example of how I have to do this, it's been a long time since I use VB. NET.

Comment: The fact that it's been a long time since you used VB.NET does not mean that you have to sit back and let someone else write your code for you. It means you have to put in a bit more effort, not less, to get done what you need to do. Make an effort to learn what you need to do, make an effort to do it and then, if it doesn't work, you have a question to ask. "I don't know how and couldn't be bothered finding out so you do it" is not how SO works.

Comment: Thank you, but this opinion is not good enough. The simple fact that I asked this question here on StackOverFlow means that I tried my hardest to solve this case, as I used my knowledge bases and research to be able to write the code above, at least I managed to get a result. And I just asked you for a basis to continue, in case it was something I didn't know I would do more research with the bases you gave me so I could reach the final result. You don't need to write all the code for me, just write the bases that I can use.

Comment: Whether you tried your best before isn't really relevant. You tried to solve the problem one way - a very bad way - and I told you to solve it in a different way. You have made no attempt at all to solve it that way so you definitely haven't tried your best. When someone provides you with new information, the first thing you need to do is try to use that information for yourself, not expect them to do everything for you. If you aren't prepared to make that effort then that's your prerogative but I won't be making more effort than you're prepared to. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: And sorry if I'm being rude.

Comment: As an example, have you read the documentation for the `Graphics.DrawString` method to see what overloads it has and how each one works? If not then you haven't tried your best because, regardless of what you're able to do with the information in that documentation, you're quite capable of reading it and following any relevant links it contains and reading those pages too.

Comment: Whether you're being rude hasn't occurred to me one way or the other. What you are doing is assuming that, once you try and fail, your responsibility for effort has ended and it's over to others to do for you. If someone points you in a different direction, you need to go off in that direct as far as you can for yourself first, then ask for help again if and only if you need it. If that happens, you'll be able to explain what you did in that direction and what happened. We all want easy answers at times. That doesn't mean that we're entitled to them.

Comment: Bad method aside, should still work.  From your image though, it's not really that clear exactly where the top of the first label is in comparison to the printing.  Have you checked the print settings, media settings, calibration etc on the printer to ensure that the top margin isn't over stated?  If the top of the printing is in the expected location, then to me simply looks like too much to fit on a page in the current formatting/layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider converting the text to image and print image to printer.

Some code you may need:

```
Private img As Bitmap
Private str As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    str.Append("Produced By:" + vbTab + vbTab + "Company")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Address")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "No. 1")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "City")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Product:" + vbTab + vbTab + "SPECIE")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Product Format:" + vbTab + "Fresh Skin OFF Loin")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Grade:" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "GRADE")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Catch Area:" + vbTab + vbTab + "FAO 51")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Storage Instructions:" + vbTab + "0.5º to 1.5º Celcius")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Establishment No.:" + vbTab + "A22.1")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Origin:" + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Origin")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Vessel Name/s:" + vbTab + vbTab + "vesselcmb.SelectedItem")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Product Date:" + vbTab + vbTab + Date.Now.Date)
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Best Before:" + vbTab + vbTab + Date.Now.Date.AddDays(16))
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Project code:" + vbTab + vbTab + "voyageprint.Text")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("Net Weight:" + vbTab + vbTab + "")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbTab + "To be further prepared for consumption")
    str.Append("" + vbNewLine)
    str.Append("" + vbTab + vbTab + "100% Natural")
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    img = ConvertTextToImage(str.ToString, "Arial", 12, Color.White, Color.Black, 840, 1188)
    Dim printDialog1 As PrintDialog = New PrintDialog()
    printDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    Dim result As DialogResult = printDialog1.ShowDialog()

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.MarginBounds)
End Sub
Public Function ConvertTextToImage(ByVal txt As String, ByVal fontname As String, ByVal fontsize As Integer, ByVal bgcolor As Color, ByVal fcolor As Color, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal Height As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(width, Height)

    Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim font As Font = New Font(fontname, fontsize)
        graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
        graphics.DrawString(txt, font, New SolidBrush(fcolor), 0, 0)
        graphics.Flush()
        font.Dispose()
        graphics.Dispose()
    End Using

    Return bmp
End Function
```

Result of my test.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. I made some basic adjustments, but it solved my problem. Keep that good heart. Thank you very much, you made my day.